# Rails - Dumping an object in a controller and aborting execution

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

How do I dump an objects contents and stop execution.  But I need to do this IN THE CONTROLLER.  debug and .to_yaml only seem to work in the view, but Googling seems to only return this as an option.

I have a controller which works on an object.  I want to be able to dump out and view the contents of this object at certain points in the execution of the action BEFORE it reaches the view.

I don't want to do it through logging or console, I just want to dump the contents of the object or variable to the screen.

Many Thanks

Comment: you might find this helpful http://nofail.de/2013/10/debugging-rails-applications-in-development/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A bit lengthy if you need to type this again and again in your view, but you could use `render text: ...` as follows:

```
class MyController < ApplicationController
  def show
    ...
    @obj = ...

    # Place the following line to inspect @obj variable
    return render text: CGI.escapeHTML(@obj.inspect)

    ...
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

```
# app/controllers/any_controller.rb
class AnyController < ApplicationController
  def index
    raise @some_object.inspect
    # some execution
    #raise @some_object.inspect
    # some execution
    # etc.
  end
end
```